# How to set bounds for a exponential distribution to be used in a Randomized Search?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy

I'm trying to find the best parameters values for a classification problem using Sci-Kit Learn. I found out that one way of doing this is by using [RandomizedSearchCV()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV)
When I was setting the dict of parameters I want my classifier to use, I ran into a problem:  I want to use a exponential distribuition between 2^-15 and 2^15 for the C and gamma parameters.

I've done some researching and I found that the [scipy.stats.expon](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.expon.html) would solve my problem. However, I have no clue of how to set the bounds that I'm looking for.

```py
scoring = {
       'accuracy': 'accuracy',
       'precision_macro': 'precision_macro',
       'recall_macro': 'recall_macro',
       'f1_macro': 'f1_macro'}

param_distributions = {
        'kernel': ['linear', 'poly', 'rbf', 'sigmoid'],
        'C': expon(), # Here are the line that I should set the distribution
        'gamma': expon(), # Also here
        'degree': randint(2, 7),
        'coef0': [0],
        'probability': [True]}

cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=4)

rdm = RandomizedSearchCV(
             estimator=SVC(),
             param_distributions=param_distributions,
             n_iter=10,
             scoring=scoring,
             n_jobs=-1,
             iid=False,
             cv=cv,
             refit='accuracy',
             random_state=787870)
rdm_results = rdm.fit(X, y)
```

How should I approach this? Is there an easy way of getting the distribution I want?

Comment: Use GridSearchCV (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) if you want to find the best parameters values from all possible combinations (Exhaustive search). RandomizedSearchCV picks randomely n_iter possible combination of parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate random floats from an exponential distribution using [numpy.random.exponential](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.exponential.html) first, then min-max scaling them using [sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale.html) as follow:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import minmax_scale
# define the number of parameters to generate 
number_of_params = 500
# generate random floats from an exponential distribution
x = np.random.exponential(scale=1.0, size=number_of_params)
# min-max scaler
x = minmax_scale(x, feature_range=(2**-15, 2**15), axis=0, copy=True)
```